# Add same line in multiple lines in variable

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have below PowerShell script to get files created from specific time:

```cs
$diff = "H:\DBBackup\server1\queryDB\Diff\"
$tlogs = "H:\DBBackup\server1\queryDB\trn\"

$compareDate = Get-Date (Get-Item $diff).LastWriteTime

$trn = Get-ChildItem -Path $tlogs | Where-Object {
    $_.LastWriteTime -gt $compareDate -and !($_.PSIsContainer)
} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime

$trn.Name
```

Below is the output of above script which is expected

```
SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_10_043503_8807816.trn
SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_10_044003_8906811.trn
SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_10_053903_4501615.trn
SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_11_032503_7408313.trn
SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_11_043003_7803417.trn
SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_11_044003_2408719.trn
```

Now I want use above values with path added in `$tlog` to run below commands in above script.

```
ascp -T -l 100m -m 10m -i "C:\Users\abc\.ssh\id_putty.ppk" H:\DBBackup\server1\queryDB\trn\SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_10_043503_8807816.trn test@192.168.22.156:/SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_10_043503_8807816.trn
ascp -T -l 100m -m 10m -i "C:\Users\abc\.ssh\id_putty.ppk" H:\DBBackup\server1\queryDB\trn\SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_10_044003_8906811.trn test@192.168.22.156:/SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_10_044003_8906811.trn
ascp -T -l 100m -m 10m -i "C:\Users\abc\.ssh\id_putty.ppk" H:\DBBackup\server1\queryDB\trn\SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_10_053903_4501615.trn test@192.168.22.156:/SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_10_053903_4501615.trn
ascp -T -l 100m -m 10m -i "C:\Users\abc\.ssh\id_putty.ppk" H:\DBBackup\server1\queryDB\trn\SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_11_032503_7408313.trn test@192.168.22.156:/SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_11_032503_7408313.trn
ascp -T -l 100m -m 10m -i "C:\Users\abc\.ssh\id_putty.ppk" H:\DBBackup\server1\queryDB\trn\SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_11_043003_7803417.trn test@192.168.22.156:/SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_11_043003_7803417.trn
ascp -T -l 100m -m 10m -i "C:\Users\abc\.ssh\id_putty.ppk" H:\DBBackup\server1\queryDB\trn\SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_11_044003_2408719.trn test@192.168.22.156:/SQLSLinuxServerDB_backup_2017_08_11_044003_2408719.trn
```

Is there any way to use above commands using string or variable in my PowerShell script instead of hardcoading it.

I tried with this

```
$LatestDiffFile = $tlogs + $trn.Name
$LatestDiffFile
```

But this is not working the way I thought.

Comment: `$tlogs + $trn[-1].Name`

Comment: `$trn | % { Join-Path $tlogs $_.Name }`

Comment: To get the fullpath, you can use `$trn.FullName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the *latest*, after sorting on `LastWriteTime`, grab the last index (`-1`) in the `$trn` array:

```
$LatestDiffFile = $tlogs + $trn[-1].Name
```

If you want to prepend `$tlogs` to *all* the names in `$trn` and issue the `ascp` command, use a loop:

```
foreach($file in $trn){
    # Construct local file path
    $LocalPath = Join-Path $tlogs $file.Name
    # Construct remote file path
    $RemotePath = 'test@192.168.22.156:/{0}' -f $file.Name
    # Prepare ascp arguments
    $ascpArgs = '-T -l 100m -m 10m -i "C:\Users\abc\.ssh\id_putty.ppk"',$LocalPath,$RemotePath

    # Execute
    & ascp $ascpArgs
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mathias R. Jessen, its working fine now.